# Design of complex table layout

Tags: tables

Is it possible to reproduce what this [image](http://ctrlv.in/636773) is showing in LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: Yes. It is possible to reproduce it in LaTeX.

Comment: I'm, uh, not sure I'd recommend it, though ...

Comment: Please do not do this. If you have a different question, ask a different question. Your question is now extremely difficult for other users to follow and make use of, because it assumes an answer to an earlier version of itself. Also, you are moving the goal posts in the middle of the game, which is not really fair. You want `\newcommand\TableRow[3]`, by the way.

Comment: @Au101 Not recommend reproducing it or not recommend doing so in LaTeX? Definitely agree with the first.

Comment: @cfr Yeah, the first :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Here's one option (the code needs two or three runs for the arrow and numbers to reach their final positions):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,tikzmark}

\newcounter{myrowa}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{FrameBox}[2]{
  enhanced,
  width=0.6\textwidth,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  colback=white,
  boxrule=1pt,
  top=0.4cm,
  bottom=0.4cm,
  before=\vskip20pt\noindent,
  fontupper=\sffamily\Large,
  overlay unbroken={
    \node[inner sep=0pt] at ([xshift=-2pt]frame.west) {\tikzmark{item-\thetcbcounter}\phantom{A}};
    \node[anchor=south west,font=\sffamily] at (frame.north west) {Goal:~#2};
  },
  colframe=#1,
}

\newcommand\TableRow[2]{%
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}
    \par\noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
       | >{\stepcounter{myrowa}\arabic{myrowa}.}p{1.5em}@{}X
       | >{\Alph{myrowa}.}p{1.5em}@{}X |
    }
    \hline & #1 & & #2\\\hline\end{tabularx}\vskip1.5pt
}

\newcommand\TableHead{%
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}
    \par\noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{YY}
    Procedural steps & Applied methods
    \end{tabularx}\vskip1.5pt
  }

\begin{document} 
   
\begin{FrameBox}{cyan}{Identify best surrogate candidates}
Identification
\end{FrameBox}
\TableHead
\TableRow{Identify software functions on different levels}{Method for functional decomposition}
\TableRow{Select}{Method of resource selection}
\TableRow{Identify software functions on different levels}{Method for functional decomposition}
\TableRow{Select}{Method of resource selection}

\begin{FrameBox}{red!80!black}{Build the prototype}
Construction
\end{FrameBox}
\TableHead
\TableRow{Identify software functions on different levels}{Method for functional decomposition}
\TableRow{Select}{Method of resource selection}
\TableRow{Identify software functions on different levels}{Method for functional decomposition}
\TableRow{Select}{Method of resource selection}

\begin{FrameBox}{orange}{Test functionality and utility}
Test
\end{FrameBox}
\TableHead
\TableRow{Identify software functions on different levels}{Method for functional decomposition}
\TableRow{Select}{Method of resource selection}
\TableRow{\tikzmark{end}Identify software functions on different levels}{Method for functional decomposition}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[gray,line width=3pt,-latex]
  ([shift={(-2pt,36pt)}]{pic cs:item-1}) -- 
  ([shift={(-2pt,-20pt)}]{{pic cs:item-1}|-{pic cs:end}});
\foreach \Valor in {1,2,3}
  \node[fill=white,draw=black!80,line width=2pt,minimum size=2em,font=\sffamily\large] 
  at ([shift={(0.2em,4pt)}]{pic cs:item-\Valor}) 
  {\Valor};  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I used [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) for the colorized frames; [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/PGF) and its [`tikzmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) library to draw the arrow and place the framed numbers and [`tabularx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) for the tabular material.

## Update

For a three-column setting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,tikzmark}

\newcounter{myrowa}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{FrameBox}[2]{
  enhanced,
  width=0.6\textwidth,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  colback=white,
  boxrule=1pt,
  top=0.4cm,
  bottom=0.4cm,
  before=\vskip20pt\noindent,
  fontupper=\sffamily\Large,
  overlay unbroken={
    \node[inner sep=0pt] at ([xshift=-2pt]frame.west) {\tikzmark{item-\thetcbcounter}\phantom{A}};
    \node[anchor=south west,font=\sffamily] at (frame.north west) {Goal:~#2};
  },
  colframe=#1,
}

\newcommand\TableRow[3]{%
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}
    \par\noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
       | >{\stepcounter{myrowa}\arabic{myrowa}.}p{1.5em}@{}Z
       | >{\Alph{myrowa}.}p{1.5em}@{}Z |
       | >{\Alph{myrowa}.}p{1.5em}@{}Z |
    }
    \hline & #1 & & #2 & & #3\\\hline\end{tabularx}\vskip1.5pt
}

\newcommand\TableHead{%
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}
    \par\noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{YYY}
     Activités à réaliser & Patrons & Exigences
    \end{tabularx}\vskip1.5pt
  }

\begin{document} 

\begin{FrameBox}{cyan}{Identify best surrogate candidates}
Identification
\end{FrameBox}
\TableHead
\TableRow{Identify software functions}{Functional decomposition}{example}
\TableRow{\tikzmark{end}Identify software functions}{Functional decomposition}{example}


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[gray,line width=3pt,-latex]
  ([shift={(-2pt,36pt)}]{pic cs:item-1}) -- 
  ([shift={(-2pt,-20pt)}]{{pic cs:item-1}|-{pic cs:end}});
\foreach \Valor in {1}
  \node[fill=white,draw=black!80,line width=2pt,minimum size=2em,font=\sffamily\large] 
  at ([shift={(0.2em,4pt)}]{pic cs:item-\Valor}) 
  {\Valor};  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Impressively little code in the end. This is an excellent example for "use the right tools for the task".

Comment: Thank you Gonzalo Medina for your answer. The render of your code gives me the table as shown on the following picture:http://ctrlv.in/637232. Do I get a different render than yours because of my environnement?
I use TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2014) on Ubuntu 12.04 and Adobe Reader 9.5.5 04/26/2013

Comment: @cProg Did you run the code two or three times? Since internal calculations are involved to place the arrow and the numbers, you need two or three compilations.

Comment: @cProg Ah, nevermind. The problem is that your table has page breaks. My solution doesn't produce good results with page breaks. Maybe I'll update with a version for this, if I have time.

Comment: I have edited my initial question to add another one.

Comment: @cProg Next time show all requirements from the beginning; otherwise, open a follow-up question.

Comment: @cProg Please see my updated answer for the case of three columns.

Comment: Thank you Gonzalo Medina, the three columns works. I have tried to fix the page overlay problem with the example given here http://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/79125/2 but didn't succeed.

Comment: @cProg You're welcome! I'm already working on the issue with page breaks. I'll let you know the result.

Comment: About that line `& #1 & & #2 & & #3` in `\newcommand\TableRow[3]` macro, I realized that no data are shown in the middle column, I mean column 2; I guess it is because `#2` has been defined above as `{Goal:~#2}` ; the content of column 3 should be the content of column 2; the normal content of column 3 is display as text out of the table. Then I tried that `& #1 & & #3 & & #4` but got the following error message:
`! Illegal parameter number in definition of \FrameBox <to be read again> 4`
I try to find framebox syntax to understand the parameters settings but couldn't.

Comment: @cProg Of course data is shown. Columns 1,3 and 5 are automatically filled with the counter (that's why they are left empty in `& #1 & & #2 & & #3`).

Comment: What `& #1 & & #2 & & #3` gives actually is represented on this picture: http://img.ctrlv.in/img/15/09/17/55fadf4a5ccad.png
The text circled in red color should be in the middle column and the text squared in blue color should be where the text circled in red color is actually.
That is why I tried both `& #1 & & #3 & & #4` and `& #1 & & #3 & & #5`: it didn't work and got the error `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \FrameBox <to be read again>`. I wonder how to display the right way my data.

Comment: @cProg Without seeing the actual code you are using (not just useless snippets, but a proper MWE), it's impossible to tell I already told you what to do: open a follow-up question.